# Lua puts of variable name instead of variable value in table

Tags: lua

Hello guys i am trying to add Divisions to a game but there is a problem with tables, do you guys know how to solve this?

```lua
local divisonName = result3[i].name
print(divisonName)
ESX.Divisions[result3[i].owner].divisonName = {}
```

it's the code it should get division name and create a table with that like this  (we assume divisonName gonna return swat for example):

```lua
["police"] = {
    ["swat"] = {
        },
    },
```

but instead of putting division name as SWAT it will put divisionName variable
i already print that divisionName variable and console return me SWAT so everything is fine with logic and value of variable but i guess there it's syntax issue i am not sure!
[Console Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRGe3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in Lua the construct `some_table.field` is a syntactic sugar for `some_table["field"]`. Whatever is written after the dot will be treated as a string key.

In your case, to index by the value stored in the variable, you need to write `ESX.Divisions[result3[i].owner][divisonName]`, and not as `.divisionName`.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved me <3